# Making solid fuel out of sugar

Tags: combustion, carbohydrates, fuel

I recently tried to make a cheap solid fuel out of sugar. First I attempted burning the sugar cube directly, which did not work well even using a blowtorch. This was expected. Then I attempted to use paper ash, and it could be lit with a lighter. However the flame went out quickly and that would not be usable for anything.

How can I make sugar burn completely? My aim is to have it burn as well as hexamine, although I realize that is probably quite impossible to do at a reasonable cost or else it would already have been done.

One idea I have had is to mix a small amount of oxidizer into the sugar - not enough to make it into a rocket-candy type fuel, but just enough to accelerate combustion. Another idea I have thought of is to mix some charcoal, combustible oil, or wood into the sugar as a secondary fuel. I won't be able to do these experiments for quite some time due to a lack of resources.